# Rails PostgreSQL migration giving error related to foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

My issue: migrated from SQLITE3 today to POSTRESQL 9.4 on my Rails app. I've looked in StackOverflow, and also followed the instructions here: http://sevenseacat.net/2015/02/24/add_foreign_key_gotchas.html

Can't seem to figure this out. Error is:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "birds" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "appointments" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_5464f9f71b"
FOREIGN KEY ("bird_id")
  REFERENCES "birds" ("id")
```

I've also gotten the above error in relation to my appointments table - pretty much the same deal.

If I remove foreign keys from all tables, migration works perfectly!

Here's my birds migration:

```
class CreateBirds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension "plpgsql"
    create_table :birds do |t|
      t.references :customer, index: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :breed
      t.string :color
      t.string :age
      t.string :notes
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :birds, :customers, column: :customer_id
  end
end
```

and the model:

```
class Bird < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :appointments

  def self.search(search)
    where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

I've adjusted and readjusted these files based on advice I've gotten from other sources and can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Do your migrations create the `birds` table *before* the `appointments` table?

Comment: Ah - I think this was the issue. I ran each migration individually, starting with customers. Then birds, then appointments, then devise_users. That seems to have worked. Any idea why this isn't running on its own? It ran fine when I was using SQLITE3.

Comment: I don't use the SQLite driver but I'm guessing that it doesn't support [foreign keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) in the database, the PostgreSQL does. You can't reference a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep - now it works, just have to remember to migrate each table separately.

Comment: @muistooshort I think you should put that as an answer because you solved LadyStensberg's problem, and you can get the rep from your answer being accepted.

Comment: @IsaiahZwick-Schachter Thanks but I have no shortage of rep and I've answer this question before.

Comment: @muistooshort If it's the same question then you should mark a dupe right?

Comment: @muistooshort Oh you did...

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry for the dupe. I couldn't find my answer before. :)